# Leaflet.label not showing over the markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, z-index, leaflet

I am having a set of geoJSON points and they have corresponding labels attached to them.

```
var points = L.geoJson (null, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.options.riseOnHover=true; //tried adding this
        layer.options.riseOffset=9999; //as well as this
        layer.bindLabel(feature.properties["name"], {className: 'map-label'});
        L.setOptions(layer, {riseOnHover: true}); //this as well
    }
});
```

This is the code that goes through each feature in JSON file and creates set of points. Now, the actual function that adds markers to the map goes like this:

```
var addJsonMarkers = function() {
    map.removeLayer(markers);
    points.clearLayers();

    markers = new L.layerGroup();
    points.addData(dataJson);
    markers.addLayer(points);

    map.addLayer(markers);

    return false;
};
```

The issue I am having is that no matter what I try to add (you can see my comments), the labels are always behind the markers, which is not the expected behavior.

[image: Screenshot of label behind the]

I would like the label to be on top of it. I tried manually changing the `z-index` in the `map-label` class, as well as numerous solutions with `riseOnHover` which seems to be the solution for this, but the labels are still behind. Anyone seeing what I am doing wrong?

The complete code can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/2iH3U0a7)

Comment: You need to look to see what pane of the map the label is being attached to and move it to one above the markers.  You might also look at {optimized: false} for the markers (if it is available).

Comment: It is being attached to the `leaflet-marker-pane`, as the last element in the list of all markers in the div.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify `popupPane` as `pane` in `bindLable` options:

```
layer.bindLabel(
    feature.properties["name"], 
    {
        className: 'map-label', 
        pane:'popupPane'
    }
);
```

In Leaflet popupPane is higher than markerPane so your labels will appear on top of markers.

There is a small doc for Leaflet.label with options description https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label

Also check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L6kqu54a/

Comment: This did it. I overlooked this option in the documentation and searched for solution in wrong places. Thanks!

Comment: Just confirming the *options.pane = 'popupPane';* solution. I did not have this problem in LeafletJS 0.7.3 and 0.7.5 but it came to haunt me when I switched to LeafletJS 1.0.0-beta. Fiddling with zIndex through JS and/or CSS simply does not work. But using options.pane does.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the bringToFront() and bringToBack() Methods, create a group function for the markers and bring it to back, meanwhile doing the opposite with labels. Or you could add a L.info to show up the information if you don't find out a solution. Take a look here maybe this could help: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup-bringtofront
Post your code somewhere too so I can take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You can take a look at my code here: http://pastebin.com/2iH3U0a7 I am not really familiar of how to do more advanced stuff, like creating group functions for markers and for labels, as I am relying on this Leaflet.label plugin and its `bindLabel()` function, so I am unsure what is actually being done in the background.

Comment: Try commenting this: layer.on({ click: highlightFeature });

Comment: Still the same. However, I need that listener, because when the marker is clicked, I get a nice info popup in the right corner with some of the contents. `<somehtml>` is just a placeholder.

Comment: have you tried to move the css pane order ? check the leaflet.css

Comment: What do you mean by moving the pane order?