# How to show label over markers on leaflet in R?

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27282601/6103040) and [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/171706).

There are two solutions given in JavaScript. 
I don't know JS at all and wanted to know how these solutions could be adapted to be used with **the R package leaflet**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying the option `options = markerOptions(riseOnHover = TRUE)` in the function for adding markers seems to work.